# How to delete my own message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a role to a person, which I have done, but also want to delete the message right after. Any I ideas on how to delete the message?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def addrole(ctx, *, role):
    user = ctx.message.author 
    try:
        await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=role)) 
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send('Only the team you are on please! Error: ' + str(e))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you get from context can just be called:

```py
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Then I get the error: Error: object method can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Are you running the newest version of discord.py? Because this code should work completely fine and is an async method: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete

Comment: Yeah, I got it. The code works now. I have now idea why that happened, but thanks so much!